# PHP script that strips Google URLs from RSS feeds generates runaway process on server

Tags: php, rss

I have a PHP script that someone wrote for me that takes a Google Alert feed and strips the Google portions of the URL for each feed item, producing a standard RSS feed with links directly to the original source URLs.

For instance, it takes a Google Alert URL and runs it through the script like this:
    http://foo.com/feeds/xml-converter.php?file_name=[path to output file]&tempfile=[path to tempfile]&link=[Google Alert URL]

The result is a clean RSS feed minus the Google redirect information.

Here's the script:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(60);
$link = 'variable';
$tempfile = 'variable';
$file_name = 'variable';
extract($_GET);

//load xml and save to temp file
$xml=simplexml_load_file($link) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xml->asXml($tempfile);

//load xml from temp file
$xml=simplexml_load_file($tempfile) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

//iterate all the linkmy
foreach($xml->entry as $entry) {
    $url =  $entry->link['href'];
    preg_match("/url=(.*?)&/",$url,$program);
    $entry->link['href'] =$program[1];
}
if (file_exists($file_name) && isset($link)  && isset($file_name)) {
    unlink($file_name);
}
$xml->asXml($file_name);
unlink($tempfile);
?>
```

The script generally works fine and runs in much less than a second in most cases.

However, the problem I'm experiencing is that on occasion the process that runs the script on the server keeps running endlessly at 100% processor usage.

When I use strace to watch what's happening, I get these three steps over and over again for hours at a time, endlessly:

```
wait4(-1, 0x7ffcc3390550, WNOHANG|__WALL, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
getdents(5, /* 170 entries */, 32768)   = 5088
wait4(-1, 0x7ffcc3390550, WNOHANG|__WALL, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
getdents(5, /* 170 entries */, 32768)   = 5088
wait4(-1, 0x7ffcc3390550, WNOHANG|__WALL, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
getdents(5, /* 170 entries */, 32768)   = 5088
```

etc.

I run this script on a cron job, and while it works just fine most of the time, it occasionally creates a never-ending process. Over time, multiple processes get stuck running this way, all pegged at 100% of processor.

I'm hoping someone can tell me how I can improve the script to prevent this unfortunate and unexpected occasional result from happening.

Comment: That trace doesn't look related to the code you posted. `getdents` is used to list the files in a directory, it would be used by `readdir()` or `glob()`.

Comment: I understand your point, but the problem I'm finding is that when I do a search throughout the account for php scripts that contain "getdents" or "readdir" or "glob" I find that there are none!

Comment: Can you find the line in the trace that calls `opendir` and returns `5`? Seeing what directory it's listing might shed some light.

Comment: I think I know what's been happening, although I don't know how to prove it. I'd been running the script under 24 different cron jobs for 24 different Google Alert lists. I discovered that I'd accidentally set six of them to run once every 10 minutes, the others to run once every 6 hours. I changed them to all run once every 12 hours instead, to minimize the impact on Google. 36 hours into my test, the problem has not recurred.

Comment: I'm still not sure why this solution works, but apparently getdents plays a role in a manner that I cannot uncover. The issue went away when I changed my chron job schedule to fetch feeds from Google Alerts on a more reasonable schedule. A week later, the problem has not returned since I made this change. So while I don't feel like I have enough information to post a definitive answer to my question, I'm declaring the issue resolved.